# How to get values from ManyToMany fields?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have models:

```
class SettingField(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    value = models.TextField(max_length=200)

    [...]

class Setting(models.Model):
    setting_type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=STYPES)
    fields = models.ManyToManyField(SettingField, null=True)

    [...]
```

and form:

```
class SettingsForm(forms.Form):
    login = forms.CharField(
        required=True,
        label=u'Login'
        )
    password = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.PasswordInput,
        required=True,
        label=u'Password'
        )
```

in view I have:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = SettingsForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        setting = Setting()
        setting.setting_type = 'd'
        setting.save()
        for ff in form.fields:
            setting_field = SettingField()
            setting_field.name = ff
            setting_field.value = form.cleaned_data[ff]
            setting_field.save()
            setting.fields.add(setting_field)
```

This stores setting with custom fields dependent on the form. But now I want get this data:

```
s_objs = Setting.objects.filter(setting_type='d')

logins = list()

for so in s_objs:
    logins.append({
        "login": so.fields.??? what here ???,
        "password": so.fields.??? what here ???
    })
```

How to do it? I could use a loop and compare names, but maybe there is another way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will give you a dict containing name and value for all fields related to so.

```
so.fields.all().values('name', 'value')
```

You don't want to hit the db to often so use prefetch_related on s_objs:

```
s_objs = Setting.objects.filter(setting_type='d').prefetch_related('fields')
```